# width occupying only for two lines

Tags: jquery, css

I may have short texts or long texts but anyway I want to define the width of my div so that the text would be in two lines.

**short text**

> +-------------------------+
>   | short text goes here |
>   | short text goes here |
>   +-------------------------+

**long text**

> +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
>   | long text goes here long text goes here long text goes |
>   | long text goes here long text goes here long text goes |
>   +--------------------------------------------------------------------+

So whatever the text short or long it's width be as per two lines. How can I accomplish this?

If it's not possible with css, is there anyway to accomplish this with jquery?

Comment: Definitely not possible with just CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/364Vt/1/)

**CSS:**

```
.two-lines {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.two-lines.wrapped {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(".two-lines").each(function () {
    var $width = $(this).width();
    $(this).width($width / 2)
           .addClass("wrapped");
});
```

---

**Edit: This is a more accurate way**

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/cYnp4/)

```
$(".two-lines").each(function () {
    var $lines = $(this).height() / parseInt($(this).css("lineHeight"));

    while (($lines > 2) || ($(this)[0].scrollWidth > $(this).width())) {
        $(this).width("+=1");
        $lines = $(this).height() / parseInt($(this).css("lineHeight"));
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks n +1 for your answer "nothing is impossible with jquery"

Answer (score 0):

Not with the single tag. You can however, opt for following if source modification is feasible for you:

```
<div>
    <p>long text goes here long text goes here long text goes #</p>
    <p>long text goes here long text goes here long text goes</p>
</div>

<style>
    div > p {
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
</style>
```

And both line would always be one line. Now you don't set width to your div hence it will extend to accommodate the texts.